# Regridding regular netcdf data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, earthpy

I have a netcdf file containing global sea-surface temperatures. Using matplotlib and Basemap, I've managed to make a map of this data, with the following code:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

filename = '/Users/Nick/Desktop/SST/SST.nc'
fh = Dataset(filename, mode='r')

lons = fh.variables['LON'][:]
lats = fh.variables['LAT'][:]
sst = fh.variables['SST'][:].squeeze()

fig = plt.figure()

m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlon=80.,llcrnrlat=-25.,urcrnrlon=150.,urcrnrlat=25.,lon_0=115., lat_0=0., resolution='l')

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
xi, yi = m(lon, lat)

cs = m.pcolormesh(xi,yi,sst, vmin=18, vmax=32)

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='0.3')
m.fillcontinents(color='0.3', lake_color='0.3')
cbar = m.colorbar(cs, location='bottom', pad="10%", ticks=[18., 20., 22., 24., 26., 28., 30., 32.])
cbar.set_label('January SST (' + u'\u00b0' + 'C)')
plt.savefig('SST.png', dpi=300)
```

The problem is that the data is very high resolution (9km grid) which makes the resulting image quite noisy. I would like to put the data onto a lower resolution grid (e.g. 1 degree), but I'm struggling to work out how this could be done. I followed a worked solution to try and use the matplotlib griddata function by inserting the code below into my above example, but it resulted in 'ValueError: condition must be a 1-d array'.

```
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

X = np.arange(min(x), max(x), 1)
Y = np.arange(min(y), max(y), 1)

Xi, Yi = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

Z = griddata(xi, yi, z, Xi, Yi)
```

I'm a relative beginner to Python and matplotlib, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (or what a better approach might be). Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Have you try to use [`conturf`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf), I'm finding it producing much smoother plots

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried contourf too, but it doesn't really solve the problem. With the high resolution data, the boundaries between contours are not smooth. It would be ok if I could smooth the data and then contour, but I didn't find a good way to do that yet.

Comment: How about passing exact values to `contourf` on which contours have to bee drawn, with really small intervals that should smooth data on map.

Answer (score 11):

If you **regrid** your data to a coarser lat/lon grid using e.g. bilinear interpolation, this will result in a **smoother** field.

The NCAR ClimateData guide has a nice [introduction to regridding](https://climatedataguide.ucar.edu/climate-data-tools-and-analysis/regridding-overview) (general, not Python-specific).

The most powerful implementation of regridding routines available for Python is, to my knowledge, the [Earth System Modeling Framework (ESMF) Python interface (ESMPy)](https://www.earthsystemcog.org/projects/esmp/). If this is a bit too involved for your application, you should look into

1. [EarthPy](http://earthpy.org/) tutorials on regridding (e.g. using [Pyresample](http://earthpy.org/interpolation_between_grids_with_pyresample.html), [cKDTree](http://earthpy.org/interpolation_between_grids_with_ckdtree.html), or [Basemap](http://earthpy.org/interpolation_between_grids_with_basemap.html)).
2. Turning your data into an [Iris](http://scitools.org.uk/iris/) cube and using [Iris' regridding functions](http://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/latest/userguide/interpolation_and_regridding.html#regridding).

Perhaps start by looking at the [EarthPy regridding tutorial using Basemap](http://earthpy.org/interpolation_between_grids_with_basemap.html), since you are using it already.

The way to do this in your example would be

```
from mpl_toolkits import basemap
from netCDF4 import Dataset

filename = '/Users/Nick/Desktop/SST/SST.nc'
with Dataset(filename, mode='r') as fh:
   lons = fh.variables['LON'][:]
   lats = fh.variables['LAT'][:]
   sst = fh.variables['SST'][:].squeeze()

lons_sub, lats_sub = np.meshgrid(lons[::4], lats[::4])

sst_coarse = basemap.interp(sst, lons, lats, lons_sub, lats_sub, order=1)
```

This performs bilinear interpolation (`order=1`) on your SST data onto a sub-sampled grid (every fourth point). Your plot will look more coarse-grained afterwards. If you do not like that, interpolate back onto the original grid with e.g.

```
sst_smooth = basemap.interp(sst_coarse, lons_sub[0,:], lats_sub[:,0], *np.meshgrid(lons, lats), order=1)
```

Comment: I found that `scipy.interpolate.interp2d()` is faster than basemap.

Comment: The new kid in town is [xESMF](https://github.com/JiaweiZhuang/xESMF) - ESMF interface to game-changer [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/).

Comment: xESMF requires Python3.5 or above.

Answer (score 0):

I usually run my data through a Laplace filter for smoothing. Perhaps you could try the function below and see if it helps with your data. The function can be called with or without a mask (e.g land/ocean mask for ocean data points). Hope this helps. T

```
# Laplace filter for 2D field with/without mask
# M = 1 on - cells used
# M = 0 off - grid cells not used
# Default is without masking

import numpy as np
def laplace_X(F,M):
    jmax, imax = F.shape
    # Add strips of land
    F2 = np.zeros((jmax, imax+2), dtype=F.dtype)
    F2[:, 1:-1] = F
    M2 = np.zeros((jmax, imax+2), dtype=M.dtype)
    M2[:, 1:-1] = M

    MS = M2[:, 2:] + M2[:, :-2]
    FS = F2[:, 2:]*M2[:, 2:] + F2[:, :-2]*M2[:, :-2]

    return np.where(M > 0.5, (1-0.25*MS)*F + 0.25*FS, F)

def laplace_Y(F,M):
    jmax, imax = F.shape

    # Add strips of land
    F2 = np.zeros((jmax+2, imax), dtype=F.dtype)
    F2[1:-1, :] = F
    M2 = np.zeros((jmax+2, imax), dtype=M.dtype)
    M2[1:-1, :] = M

    MS = M2[2:, :] + M2[:-2, :]
    FS = F2[2:, :]*M2[2:, :] + F2[:-2, :]*M2[:-2, :]

    return np.where(M > 0.5, (1-0.25*MS)*F + 0.25*FS, F)


# The mask may cause laplace_X and laplace_Y to not commute
# Take average of both directions

def laplace_filter(F, M=None):
    if M == None:
        M = np.ones_like(F)
    return 0.5*(laplace_X(laplace_Y(F, M), M) +
                laplace_Y(laplace_X(F, M), M))
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question regarding `scipy.interpolate.griddata`, too:

Have a close look at the parameter specs for that function (e.g. in the [SciPy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)) and make sure that your input arrays have the **right shapes**. You might need to do something like

```
import numpy as np
points = np.vstack([a.flat for a in np.meshgrid(lons,lats)]).T # (n,D)
values = sst.ravel() # (n)
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Linux, you can achieve this using nctoolkit (https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You have not stated the latlon extent of your data, so I will assume it is a global dataset. Regridding to 1 degree resolution would require the following:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
filename = '/Users/Nick/Desktop/SST/SST.nc'
data = nc.open_data(filename)

data.to_latlon(lon = [-179.5, 179.5], lat = [-89.5, 89.5], res = [1,1])
# visualize the data
data.plot()
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at this example with xarray...
use the `ds.interp` method and specify the new latitude and longitude values.

http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html#example