# How to plot numbers from an array as annotation using matplotlib?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to produce the map on basemap using vales extracted from meteorological data. Sample code is:-

```
y=[2.56422, 3.77284,3.52623,3.51468,3.02199]
z=[0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.75]
n=[58,651,393,203,123]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(z, y)

for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (z[i],y[i]))
```

[image]

The data I am using is a numpy array. I dont know how to loop through each array to plot the kind of map similar to above. I would like to plot only values (ie. no `countour` or `contourf`).

Initially I was trying to plot float values using `pylab.plot` function. However, it retured with error

```
ValueError: third arg must be a format string
```

Then I tried to convert this numpy array to string and then plot with this command:-

```
temperature = np.array2string(data, precision=2)
```

and the print statement looks like a modified string:-

```
print temperature
[[ 19.69  21.09  21.57  21.45  20.59  20.53  20.93  20.63  20.64  21.26
   21.29  20.63  20.98  21.01  20.84  20.81  20.55  20.33  20.52  20.23
   19.84]
 [ 20.77  21.35  20.81  20.64  20.9   20.78  20.79  23.57  20.11  21.07
   21.06  21.33  21.48  21.18  21.4   21.09  20.5   20.31  20.12  19.8
   19.97]
 [ 21.51  21.23  20.55  20.08  20.05  20.78  21.17  24.77  21.17  20.95
   21.43  21.47  21.46  21.77  21.69  21.13  20.47  20.04  20.08  20.37
   20.14]
 [ 21.29  21.1   20.63  20.32  20.22  20.37  24.4   23.82  22.23  21.03
   22.11  22.62  22.71  22.37  21.73  21.35  21.03  20.67  20.58  20.89
   20.93]
 [ 21.24  21.04  20.68  20.56  20.76  20.91  24.26  23.75  23.28  21.26
   21.48  22.    21.94  21.78  21.36  21.14  20.96  20.92  21.1   21.19
   21.31]
 [ 20.83  20.88  20.6   20.87  21.01  21.91  22.33  22.21  21.74  20.66
   20.76  20.73  21.04  21.09  20.83  20.7   20.72  20.71  21.23  21.04
   20.73]
 [ 20.32  20.41  20.19  20.05  20.68  22.17  21.82  20.67  19.85  19.02
   18.91  19.6   20.15  20.64  20.64  20.09  19.81  19.76  19.9   19.94
   19.46]
 [ 19.68  20.37  20.56  20.68  20.93  21.28  21.24  20.33  20.7   20.
   18.72  18.94  19.56  19.57  19.83  19.74  19.17  18.53  18.1   18.72
   19.12]
 [ 18.88  19.71  20.77  20.81  20.32  21.58  20.96  21.33  21.2   20.17
   19.95  22.05  19.72  19.85  19.3   18.75  18.69  18.44  17.57  17.2
   18.22]
 [ 19.11  19.19  20.13  20.78  21.25  21.98  21.15  20.96  20.66  20.14
   20.51  21.92  20.36  20.27  19.    18.22  17.81  17.58  17.16  16.67
   17.46]
 [ 18.5   19.28  19.57  20.01  21.16  21.01  21.06  20.93  20.62  19.89
   20.3   20.7   19.7   19.76  18.24  17.    16.36  16.63  17.62  17.32
   17.38]
 [ 17.6   18.33  20.27  19.97  20.63  20.51  21.09  21.39  20.81  19.55
   20.    18.3   17.32  18.24  17.57  17.15  16.42  15.76  16.14  16.45
   21.95]
 [ 17.04  17.55  18.16  18.32  21.23  20.5   20.41  19.82  20.7   20.55
   20.41  18.47  18.05  17.63  17.11  15.6   16.02  15.46  14.29  13.88
   23.04]]
```

Finally, I get this error when I tried to plot the above value on a map with this line

```
pylab.plot(x, y, temperature)

    'Unrecognized character %c in format string' % c)
ValueError: Unrecognized character [ in format string
```

Problem seems to be with nparray to string conversion.

Any help to solve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain the structure of your data? Do you have a regular matrix with temperature values for every pixel? Could you provide some file as example to make some test?

Comment: data --> http://www.mediafire.com/download/0epjjdm8auit611/mslp.txt  x --> http://www.mediafire.com/download/1dn6p8nw96h2mmd/xlong.txt y --> http://www.mediafire.com/download/31suzsz6j7u2bgz/xlat.txt. The first link is not a temperature value but array length is same.

Comment: What is the structure of the data? Why I get arrays of shape (178, 343)?

Comment: The working example I have posted earlier is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633421/how-to-remove-omit-smaller-contour-lines-using-matplotlib/. The code is two lines below 'Full working example code for removing lines:-'

Comment: You can see my improved question with a very simple example.

Comment: What is not working in your example with `ax.annotate`? What's the problem with that? That seems to work. If the problem is with looping over a 2d array: just loop over `n.ravel()` instead of `n`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Post with some code so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: @sundar_ima turns out there is an even better option than looping over `n.ravel()` and indexing, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original solution with `ax.annotate` is perfectly fine for your more general solution. The only thing to change is that in case of 2d arrays, you need to flatten them before looping over them using `np.ravel()` (which is also a method of the `ndarray` class).

However, in your specific case you can spare explicit indexing *and* the use of `ravel()` by `broadcast`ing the three arrays you need to plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some dummy data
rng = np.random.default_rng()
z, y = np.mgrid[:3, :3]
n = rng.integers(low=50, high=500, size=z.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(z, y)

for zz, yy, txt in np.broadcast(z, y, n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (zz, yy))
```

Note that the result of `np.broadcast` is the same as if we'd used `zip(z.ravel(), y.ravel(), n.ravel())`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works perfectly.